# Pascal "var parameter" in Python

Tags: python

In Pascal we have `var` parameters, and functions can change parameter values to new values:

```
procedure a(var S1, S2: string);
begin
  S1:= S1+'test'+S1;
  S2:= S1+'('+S2+')';
end;
```

Does Python have such a feature?  Can I change the `string` parameter inside the method, or must I use `return` and assign the variable later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python can return *multiple* values (in the form of a tuple), obsoleting the need to pass values by reference.

In your simple sample case, even if you were able to apply the same technique, you could not achieve the same result as Python strings are not mutable.

As such, your simple example can be translated to Python as:

```
def a(s1, s2):
    s1 = '{0}test{0}'.format(s1)
    s2 = '{}({})'.format(s1, s2)
    return s1, s2

foo, bar = a(foo, bar)
```

The alternative is to pass in mutable objects (dictionaries, lists, etc.) and alter their *contents*.

Answer (score 4):

This is called "pass by reference", and no, Python doesn't do it (although if you pass in a mutable object by value and change it in the function, it's changed everywhere because it's the same object.)

Comment: e.g, you could put the strings in a standard list, and manipulate the values inside the list in your function.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to do it differently in Python, see the other answers.

If you need to pass something by reference, a simple trick is passing it a list containing only 1 element, and letting the function modify `listarg[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must, you can do something like this:

```
class ValueHolder(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def a(s1, s2):
    s1.value += 'test' + s1.value
    s2.value = '{}({})'.format(s1.value, s2.value)

s1 = ValueHolder('spam')
s2 = ValueHolder('eggs')
a(s1, s2)
print s1.value, s2.value
```

But it is a quite ugly way to do so.

Better would be

- a function which returns the changed values

  ```
  def a(s1, s2):
      return s1 + 'test' + s1, s2 + 'aaa'
  ```
- or a class which holds the old and the new data.

  ```
  class StringModifier(object)
      def __init__(self, s1, s2):
          self.s1 = s1
          self.s2 = s2
      def a(self):
          self.s1 += 'test' + self.s1
          self.s2 = '{}({})'.format(self.s1, self.s2)

  sm = StringModifier('spam', 'eggs')
  sm.a()
  print sm.s1, sm.s2
  ```